# JavaFX Scene builder controller

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I am trying to manipulate the text in a TextField generated by Scene Builder. My controller looks like this:

```
@FXML
private TextField textDescr;

public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {
    textDescr = new TextField();
    assert textDescr != null : "fx:id=\"textDescr\" was not injected: check your FXML   file 'provingGroundsUI.fxml'.";
    Game.mainFSM.enter();
}
public void setText(String s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    textDescr.setText(s);
}
```

I am getting a NullPointerException. I have tried bot with and without the `textDescr = new TextField();` part. I don't quite understand....I thought that JavaFX initialized all the UI variables at the start of the program.

Comment: Does the `fx:id` of the TextField in the fxml match the name of the field in the controller? In other words, is there a `<TextField fx:id="textDescr"...` in you fxml?

Comment: Yes it does have the correct fx:id

Comment: Make sure you @Override the initialize method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How looks your FXML?
2. To manipulate the textDescr in the setText Function has a lot of risks. It is better to use a binded StringProperty:

```
    @FXML
    private Text textDescr;

    private StringProperty textProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();  

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
            assert textDescr != null : "fx:id=\"textDescr\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'TestView.fxml'.";
           textDescr.textProperty().bind(textProperty);
    }

    public ReadOnlyStringProperty textProperty(){
          return textProperty;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller class should implement `Initializable`

The `@FXML` annotation shows that the field will be initialized by the JavaFX. So make sure, you remove the `new TextField` thing.

Are you sure you assigned this controller in the FXML?

Comment: The Controller does implement `Initializable` and the controller has been saved in the FXML.

Comment: Then, what's the import of the TextField? I hope it isnt `java.awt.TextField`

Comment: `import javafx.scene.control.TextField;`